# Can I use xml to present pages instead of using html?

Tags: xml

XML doesn't have format info, so how could I format it into nice UI? Any best practice?

And what's the pros and cons of using xml to present pages?

Thanks.

Comment: [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), which can transform XML into HTML for you.

Comment: @paolo: `<root><name>Fred</name></root>` is not going to look pretty, no matter how much CSS you throw at it.

Comment: I assumed xml=xhtml .... dunno if I was wrong

Comment: @Paolo: You can style XML with CSS, but XML and HTML are two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two takes on this:

You can generate HTML as XHTML, which is approximately HTML that is well-formed (google on this separately for the differences). You can generate the XHTML like you generate other XML docs, but its more messy as you still need to include the styling/formatting elements.

Or:

Generate XML for content, then apply an XSLT transformation to turn this into HTML. Once you've done the stylesheet once it should be fairly re-usable.

Browsers such as IE will display XML directly, but they are basically doing the latter of the above options - applying a standard stylesheet to render the xml as html (and adding the +- buttons and so on). Its not in a format that the average Joe would follow though.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, the answer XML + XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)